# Fetch data from website using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, .net, html-agility-pack

I am developing an app in which I have to fetch data from website. The format of website is:

```
<div id="id1" class="class1">
    <ol class="cls_ol">
    <li>
       <div class="class2">Content 1</div>
       <div class="cls_img">
                *** Code for some image ***
       </div>
       Content 2
    </li>
    <li>  *** Same like above <li> ***  </li>
    <li>  *** Same like above <li> ***  </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

I use code for fetching this...

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var obj = new HtmlWeb();
    var document = obj.Load(" ** url of a website ** ");

    var bold = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='class1']");

    foreach (var i in bold)
    {
        Response.Write(i.InnerHtml);
    }
```

But, the problem with my code is this, it also fetches the images of `<div class="cls_img"></div>`. I don't need this image. So, how to fetch all the content of `<div id="id1" class="class1">` without fetch the image from `<div class="cls_img">`.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 - select and remove images inside the `<div class="cls_img">` inside the `<div class="class1">` tag:

```
  var images = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(
      "//div[@class='class1']//*//div[@class='cls_img']//img"
  );

  // note that if no nodes found "images" variable will hold a null value
  foreach (var image in images)
  {
      image.Remove();
  }
```

Step 2 - select `<div class="class1">` elements (you already done it) - now without that images:

```
  var bold = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='class1']");
  foreach (var node in bold)
  {
      Console.Write(node.InnerHtml);
  }
```

Comment: Hey! Alex, can you help me out. Actually I am a novice in HtmlAgilityPact. I want to learn it. I want to learn its classes like HtmlNode class, HtmlNodeCollection class etc. So, please tell me source( like any website or ebook), from where i can learn it.

Comment: @Sagar Kadam, as far as I know it doesn't have documentation yet (instead of it you're proposed to visit theirs [Discussions tab](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/discussions) to ask questions). Also there are a lot of examples here, at [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-agility-pack). Also when you have decided the answer is most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer.

Comment: Ya! Alex, I think you are right. I searched a lot related to Agilitypack tutorial but I found nothing. I think, I should prefer  `stackoverflow` to learn it. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the nodes and find a node with the matching attribute of class="cls_img" and remove that node.

```
node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
```